# xna networking problems

Tags: c#, xna

We're working on a multiplayer game, however we've run into some problems testing. I just realized we need to launch the game on two computers to be able to test it, however it seems I cannot use the same gamer tag (or Live account if you will) for both clients. What exactly do we need to test?

I've got a paid XNA creators club membership. The other developer has a Windows Live ID and a gamer tag. When we try to launch the Client/Server example on two machines on the local network we get an error message stating that no game sessions can be found.

Any ideas?

```
/muxare
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the both computers are on the same subnet. The "type" (Creators Club, Gold etc.) of account should not really matter, both account can actually be local silver accounts. :)